# How to check if given columns exist in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have quite a few stored procedures and we are planning to remove some columns from an existing table used by those stored procedures. How can I check if the stored procedure have dependencies on those columns?

Answer (score 2):

I use this query snippet to check for columns and such within stored procedures.  It may give false/positives depending on the column names.  it looks for certain text to be within the stored procedure, not for column names.

Just replace the "addressprof" with the column name.

```
SELECT So.Name AS 'storProc'
  FROM
       Sysobjects So JOIN Syscomments Sc ON So.Id = Sc.Id
 WHERE So.Type = 'P' AND Sc.Text LIKE '%addressprof%'
 order by so.Name;
```